# How to create a UUID from a known hex string and store it in MongDB using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I need to convert some hex strings that I have into UUIDs, and store them in MongoDB.

I tried the following:

```
import pymongo
import uuid
[...]
document = { '_id': 123, 'my_uuid': uuid.UUID('b7aef1d4830843750f3846b34606528f') }
my_collection.save(document)
```

But this inserts a LUUID instead a UUID.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by LUUID? PyMongo just stores the data from UUID.bytes as BSON binary.

Comment: I mean that when I see the document through a client application, like Robomongo, its datatype is identified as LUUID, instead of UUID. According to Robomongo docs, an LUUID is a "Legacy UUID".

Answer (score 2):

> But this inserts a LUUID instead a UUID.

LUUID isn't a BSON or PyMongo type. It's just a name that [Robomongo uses](http://robomongo.org/articles/uuids.html) to denote a UUID stored as BSON binary with subtype 3 instead of subtype 4.

```
 For example the source code of UuidRepresentation class in mongodb java library:
 /**
  * The representation to use when converting a UUID to a BSON binary value.
  * This class is necessary because the different drivers used to have different
  * ways of encoding UUID, with the BSON subtype: \x03 UUID old.
  *
  * @since 3.0
  */
 public enum UuidRepresentation {
     /**
      * The canonical representation of UUID
      *
      * BSON binary subtype 4
      */
     STANDARD,

     /**
      * The legacy representation of UUID used by the C# driver
      *
      * BSON binary subtype 3
      */
     C_SHARP_LEGACY,

     /**
      * The legacy representation of UUID used by the Java driver
      *
      * BSON binary subtype 3
      */
     JAVA_LEGACY,

     /**
      * The legacy representation of UUID used by the Python driver, which is the same
      * format as STANDARD, but has the UUID old BSON subtype (\x03)
      *
      * BSON binary subtype 3
      */
     PYTHON_LEGACY
 }
```

See the [BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) for more information binary subtypes. You are, in fact, storing a UUID. If you are determined to see UUID in Robomongo instead of LUUID, then you can switch the UUID representation in PyMongo like this:

```
client = MongoClient(uuidRepresentation='standard')
```

I recently wrote up the history [in this ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-801).